# Run Apache2 as a different user with mod_event on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: server, apache2

I have Ubuntu 20.04 having configured apache2 to serve website on HTTP/2 protocol. I use mpm-event as multi processing module. Can anybody please tell me how to run apache as different user based on websites hosted on the server. I cannot use mpm-itk because it is not compatible with HTTP/2 protocol. Thanks in advance for the guidance.

Comment: To clarify, you want to have multiple instances of Apache running on the machine with each instance being owned by a different user account? Or is this just one instance of Apache that is not using the default `www-data` user account? 

Comment: I want to have multiple instances of Apache running on the same machine with each instance owned by different user account.